# Does the PS4's manufacturer warranty cover international purchases?

Tags: ps4

I want to buy a PS4 from the USA for use in India, but I'm worried that if something goes wrong that I won't be covered by warranty.

Does Sony's manufacturer warranty cover for the complete product, i.e. is it an international warranty from Sony?

Furthermore, will a USA console work in India?

Comment: Hi Rahul! Check the provided link! Ask long as India uses the same AC voltage as USA, you should be good to go for the most part.

Comment: @NBN-Alex I know about that , but I am confused regarding the warranty

Comment: You may need to be more specific. What exactly about the warranty are you confused about? Edit the question to remove anything that has already been answered by the duplicate, and add some more information about the warranty (specifically the parts you are concerned about) so we can help you out.